# Trouble with writing .zip file on server in python

Tags: python

I trying write .zip file, what i getting from HTTP

decode data from base 64:

```
dataFile = base64.b64decode(b64DataString)
```

make zipfile from bytes:

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(dataFile), "w")
```

trying to write my .zip file:

```
zf.write('C:\temp\file.zip')
```

and here, on "write('C:\temp\file.zip')" i allways get "OSError". What i am doing wrong?

Comment: It could sound stupid a bit, but are you sure your server is running on Windows?

Comment: It is Windows 10, can be reason in lack of admin privileges at the my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [previous issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python), there're a couple of ways to can provide a path to `write` method:

- Escape dashes, so it'll look as `'C:\\temp\\file.zip'`
- Use "raw" form, so it'll look as `r'C:\temp\file.zip'`
- Use `pathlib` (possibly a best solution, because cross-platform) so it'll look as:

```
import pathlib
pathlib.Path('C:/temp/file.zip')
```